# How to change language at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

In my iOS app I need an option to change language. Can we change it without changing the language in the device settings

Comment: go through link .This will solve your problem 



http://createdineden.com/blog/post/language-changer-in-app-language-selection-in-ios/

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to set the language

```
- (void) setLanguage:(NSString*) lang {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj"]; 
if (path == nil) {
    myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
} else { 
    myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
}
if (myBundle == nil) {
    myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
}
}
```

And after that you can get the localizations with

```
- (NSString*) localizedStringForKey:(NSString*) key {
   return [myBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example store different static json/plist and etc in your app with different languages strings and when you switch option parse this and set to labels.

Comment: how do you switch the option ?

Comment: In UI you can add a switch button in some settings page or in code check in code `[NSLocale currentLocale]` or `[NSLocale systemLocale]` but for it better use a standard localized.strings

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try this code once using NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* languages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[languages insertObject:@"de" atIndex:0]; // ISO639-1
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```